# Having Oozie Coordinator retrigger a workflow based off an updated dataset

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I currently have an Oozie coordinator that has a dependency on a dataset.  The dataset has been configured to create a _SUCCESS file on completion to trigger the workflow.  From my understanding, the workflow gets triggered based on the existence of the _SUCCESS file, but I have a use case where I need to retrigger the workflow to run in the case that the same _SUCCESS get updated i.e. timestamp changes.  I was wondering how I would go about this in Oozie.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you changed the dataset and updated `_SUCCESS` file. In this case I would move dataset to another path.

For instance, your dataset is located in `/user/%name%/data/2015-01-12` and the coordinator has done job for this dataset. After modification you can move your dataset to `/user/%name%/data/2015-01-16` and the coordinator will process new dataset next time.

Comment: So in my simplistic case, I have an oozie job that all it does it do a distcp from an aws directory to hdfs.  This job has a dataset that will produce a data out in say /data/todayDate i.e _SUCCESS file.  I have another oozie job that get triggered based on that data out/in from the prior dataset; this workflow runs a spark job.  

What happens if the distcp workflow runs more than once for today's date?  It will create  _SUCCESS files in the same directory, which is fine, but I would need the 2nd workflow (spark) to run for same number of times as the distcp workflow.

Comment: I see use-case. I just can offer to create separate dataset with the same path pattern but different date when distcp job runs. After that you can combine  the previous dataset and current and do useful job